# Who are Pitris?

Tags: puranas, itihasa

I used to think Pitris are our departed ancestors. We do tarpans for them. Also, invite them during the Shraddh ceremony (last rite). But, I read recently that they are not our ancestors. They are kind of Gods. It is very confusing. If they are Gods, why do we do tarpan for them? For example, before the Durga Puja, at the end of the Pitri Paksha, people in Bengal do tarpans. Who are these Pitris? Please answer quoting primary sources.

Comment: I believe ancestors were considered gods who went to devaloka or something. But I don't have any solid understanding here either.

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha Yes. But I heard some ancestors go to Pitriloka. I guess, there are two lokas, where our ancestors go - either Devaloka or Pitriloka. Not sure.

Comment: I'm not very confident either. These are some of the realms that I've not much explored.

Comment: Pitris are one's own deceased forefathers. The mantra that one chants while offering Tarapana, is "Asmatpitru-pitamah-prapitamaha.." "Asmanmatrupitamahi-prapitamah..." "Asmanmatamah-mhapramatamah-mhavruddhapramatamah..." Indicating that the tarapana is given till three generations, one's own parents, Grandparents and to the great grandparents, from both side of mother and father.

Answer (score 1):

Pitris were created by Brahma. The incident is described in Devi Bhagavad.

> Before the creation, the Creator created seven Pitris. Four out of them are with forms and the other three are of the nature of Teja (light). Seeing the beautiful and lovely forms of the Pitris, He made arrangements for their food in the form of Śrāddhas and Tarpanas, etc. (funeral ceremony and peace-offerings), etc. (Śrādh, solemn obsequies performed in honour of the manes of deceased ancestors.) - *Devi Bhagavatam 9.44.2-3*

In the footnote, the translator wrote the following verse

> Kavyavāhoanalah Somo Yamaschaivāryamā tathā
> Agnisvāttāh Barhisadah Somapā Pitri Devatāh

and mentioned that these seven Pitris (Anala, Soma, Yama, Aryamā, Agnisvāttāh, Barhisadah and Somapā) are according to the other Purānas. This verse is actually from Vayupurana (Vayu Purana 110.10).

Kalika Purana also mentions a few names.

> O the superiors of the twice-born ones! The group of Pitṛs, the Agniṣvāttas and Varhiṣads, arose from those drops of perspiration which fell from his (Brahmā) body. - *Kalika Puran 2.46*

> O the twice-born ones! It is said that the Agniṣvāttas are sixty-four thousand in number while the Varhiṣads are eighty-six thousand. - *Kalika Puran 2.48*

Other names were also mentioned.

> They are known as Somapā, Ājypa, Sukālin and Havirbhuja (Haviṣmat)- all of them take kavya (an oblation of food offered to the deceased ancestors). - *Kalika Puran 2.53*

References -

1. [Devi Bhagavatam](https://saraswat-prakashan.weebly.com/srimad-devi-bhagavatam.html)
2. [Kalika Purana](https://archive.org/details/QCML_the-kalika-puran-translated-in-english-by-b-n-shastri-edited-by-surendra-pratap-nag-publishers-/page/n45/mode/2up)
3. Vayu Purana